# How to understand interrupt handling example in The Zynq Book

Tags: c, interrupt-handling, zynq

Sorry for [cross posting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305820/problem-understending-interrupt-handling-example-in-zynq-book) but no one replied for a month. It might be a basic question but I'm coming to embedded/fpga (as a hobby) from 'big' computers and I have trouble understanding example code from [book](http://www.zynqbook.com/):

```
void BTN_Intr_Handler(void *InstancePtr)
{
    // Disable GPIO interrupts
    XGpio_InterruptDisable(&BTNInst, BTN_INT);
    // Ignore additional button presses
    if ((XGpio_InterruptGetStatus(&BTNInst) & BTN_INT) !=
            BTN_INT) {
            return;
        }
    btn_value = XGpio_DiscreteRead(&BTNInst, 1);
    // Increment counter based on button value

    led_data = led_data + btn_value;

    XGpio_DiscreteWrite(&LEDInst, 1, led_data);
    (void)XGpio_InterruptClear(&BTNInst, BTN_INT);
    // Enable GPIO interrupts
    XGpio_InterruptEnable(&BTNInst, BTN_INT);
}
```

- I would expect that for such simple code it would be just top half. However top half would execute just in IRQ mode with interrupts disabled so there is no need for disabling interrupts. OTOH if we are in bottom half there is race between button interrupt and disabling interrupts - unless we use it as a mutex for led_data.
- In similar way why if GetStatus returns we don't re-enable interrupts?

Comment: What is the book (and page), and what is the device (not only chip, but also is it PL or PS, and what is in FPGA, and what is the bus to the BTN device)? Where this code is placed, what is the OS? Some devices may have unusual Interrupt handling rules. "if GetStatus returns" - if **the interrupt line is shared** between 2 devices (same id: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt#Difficulty_with_sharing_interrupt_lines and http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-10-sect-5), two handlers will be called: each checking its device and if it was not from this device, don't work with it.

Comment: @osgx It's called The Zynq Book. I cannot find page ATM - possibly it is just in examples? No OS - standalone app. Bus is, well, AXI. I understand why XGpio_InterruptGetStatus might be called - I don't understand why we disable interrupts without re-enabling them on this codepath.

Comment: Just a shot into blue: If there are multiple interrupt handlers (for multiple buttons) and `XGpio_InterruptGetStatus()` detects that the current  handler was called for the wrong button, then the call of the right handler might be already pending. The latter will call `XGpio_InterruptEnable()` after button has been processed. Thus, it would make sense not to re-enable the interrrupts in the "wrong" handler. There is probably only a flag to enable/disable interrupts - not a counter which counts nested disables. But, it's just speculation (with no specific background).